# Issue with sending SSE from express

Tags: node.js, express, server-sent-events

We are using microservices architecture for our project. Our project is similar to a blog. There is an **activities** service, which logs all the activities done by the user, like, adding post, comment, replying to a comment and so on.

Now for each activity, we need to send an SSE notification to the involved users. For this, we are using another service called **notifications**. So whenever an activity occurs, an HTTP request will be sent to notifications service which handles sending various SSE events.

However, we are facing some issues in sending SSE. The two major issue we are facing are **memory leak** and an error **Error: write after end**

**Route**

```
router
    .route("/")
    .get(controller.eventStream)
    .post(controller.sendNotification);
```

**Controller**

```
import axios from "axios";
import eventEmitter from '../services';

const controller = {
  eventStream: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Inside event stream");
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
    });

    eventEmitter.on("sse", (event, data) => {
      console.log('Event Triggered');
      res.write(`event: ${event}\ndata: ${JSON.stringify(data)} \n\n`);
    });

    req.on("close", () => {
      console.log("Inside Close");
      res.end();
    });
  },

  sendNotification: (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const {
        userId,
        action,
        type,
        item_id,
      } = req.body;

      // First check the type of activity that has been performed
      switch (type) {
        case "topic":
          // Then check the type of action that has been done
          switch (action) {
            case "edit":
              console.log("Topic edited");
              const data= 'John Doe has edited a topic';
              eventEmitter.emit("sse", `edit-topic`, data);
              break;
          }
          break;
      }
      res.send('sse successfully send');
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({error: 'SSE failed'});
    }
  }
};

export default controller;
```

**Service**

```
export default new events.EventEmitter();
```

Initally client side will send a **GET** request which executes the `eventStream` controller.

Now for each activity, an SSE needs to be sent through this stream

I believe **Error: write after end** is because the event is triggered after sending a respose. This can be fixed by removing `res.send('sse successfully send');` However, node will throw the timeout error.

I am not sure how to send an SSE from `sendNotification` controller. Moreover, I am not sure whether this is the right approach. Any guidence would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add `import eventEmitter from '../services';` code?

Comment: @galkin '../services' contain only a single line of code 
export default new events.EventEmitter();